# Algorithmically approximable numbers - theory?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, algorithms

You could consider a real number to be "algorithmically approximable" if there is an algorithm that produces a sequence of rational numbers that converges against this number. This would obviously include algebraic numbers, and numbers like $\pi$ and $e$. The set of these numbers would be countable.

Is there a developed theory of this kind of numbers (or similarly defined numbers)? Some "real" analysis, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for these number is the [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). In general the resulting fields have the usual names except with the word "computable" in front of them. Of particular note is the development of [computable analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540668176). Computable group theory and computable combinatorics (which is mostly interested in graph theory and computable cardinals) also an ongoing field of research.